# Makefile: Unterminated String

Tags: makefile

I have the following `Makefile` and I keep getting `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string` errors:

```
BASE=/mnt/c/Users/kilgore/scripts
SCRIPTS=$(BASE)/scripts
CSV=$(BASE)/csv

DIR=
QUOTED_DIR := $(patsubst %, "%", $(DIR))
REPORTS=./$(firstword $(subst ., ,$(subst /, ,$(QUOTED_DIR))))/reports

SH_INV=$(SCRIPTS)/inventory.sh
PY_INV=$(SCRIPTS)/filecheck.py
CSV_NAME=$(shell echo "$(DIR)" | sed -r "s/[[:punct:][:space:]]//g")

.PHONY: peek csv scan

peek:
        find "$(DIR)"* -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec sh -c 'echo -n "{}: "; find "{}" -type f -print | wc -l' \;

scan:
        bash $(SH_INV) "$(DIR)"

dir:
        @echo "$(DIR)"
        @echo $(REPORTS)

INVENTORY=$(CSV)/$(CSV_NAME)_inventory.csv
REPORT=$(CSV_NAME)_inventory.xlsx

$(INVENTORY):
        bash $(SH_INV) "$(DIR)" >$@

$(REPORT): $(INVENTORY)
        unoconv -d spreadsheet -f xlsx -i FilterOptions=9,34 -o "$(REPORTS)/$(REPORT)" $<

report: $(REPORT)


report2:
        python3 $(PY_INV) -f "$(REPORTS)/$(REPORT)"
```

If I remove quotes for guarding against directories with spaces, it goes away. However, I have directories with spaces.

How can I process directories with spaces and get rid of the `unterminated` error?

Comment: In looking around, I see that `GNU Make` has no readable, simple way to deal with paths with spaces.

Comment: Yes. The most simple approach is to rename your directories and files to not contain whitespace characters.